# Matplotlib Mosaic Share Axes Labels and Ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Trying to share x and y axis across axes in figure using [mosaic](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/mosaic.html) in Matplotlib.

Example from link:

```
mosaic = """
    AB
    CD
    """
fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained")
ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic(mosaic)
```

But this yields the x and y axis ticks and labels on all four axes objects.

I want the y axis ticks to be on the same scale with only labels on the A and C axes going down the left hand side of the figure.

Similarly I want the x-axis ticks and labels going across the bottom of the figure on the C and D axes, with axes objects above to be on the same scale and only have labels across the bottom.

Using other axes creation methods this format has worked:

```
# share x and y
ax3 = plt.subplot(313, sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
```

But when trying this approach I get the following execption:

```
AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'sharex'
```

What should I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can share x and y axis by using the `sharex` and `sharey` methods that are defined on the axes object themselves.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplot_mosaic('YY\nAB\nCD', layout='constrained', figsize=(5, 3))

ax['A'].plot(range(10), range(10))
ax['C'].sharex(ax['A'])
```

For sharing multiple axes, you can use a convenient one-liner:

```py
_ = [ax[i].sharey(ax['A']) for i in 'BCD']
```

For turning on and off the axis labels, use:

```py
_ = [ax[i].tick_params(labelbottom=False) for i in "AB"]
_ = [ax[i].tick_params(labelleft=False) for i in "BD"]
```

This is what the above statements give:

[image: shared axes]

Comment: You've shown part of the solution I was looking for, can you include how to remove labels from the other axes while leaving them on the ones as described in the original question?  The one liner is impressive, if label removal can be in similar fashion would be desirable.

Comment: I edited my answer to be consistent with your question